# NetBeans Platform and JAR download

Tags: netbeans, jar, pom.xml, netbeans-platform

i'm started to use NetBeans Platform for the first time but i've got a problem.

When i do "New Project" -> "Project form archetype" -> "Next", NetBeans opens a new empty window  for define the Archetype and it freezes.

I think that is the same problem that i've when i open a Platform project and i try to create a new Window; in this case, Netbeans tries to downloading the .JAR defined in the POM file of the project without success saying "Download NetBeans Platform JARs" (org-openide-util-RELEASE80)

[image]

How can i avoid this step of download?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is downloading the netbeans-platform artefacts in the background. It should only happen the first time that you try create a platform project.

Once the artefacts have downloaded you should see that list populate, it could take a couple of minutes

Comment: The problem is that this procedure starts everytime i add a new Window in the project;
I've already created others Window in the same project and others Platform-project, but Netbeans continues to download the JAR for one hour